# How to make Node and React app to share classes

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript

I'm building a Node and React app, both using TypeScript. Its directories tree is as follows:

[image]

**My question:**

Since I'm using the same language for both stacks, and in the future the React Native will be added also using TypeScript, I wonder how I can create one group of classes to be used for all of them.

**Why I want to do this:**

DRY (Don't repeat yourself): My intention is to take full advantage of using the same programming language in all layers so there's no sense creating two equal classes.

**What I have tried so far:**

I created a third folder called "util" and put a generic class just to test both Node and React using it. Like this:

[image]

In Node.js I used the command below to import it:

```
import Person from "../../util/person.class";
```

And in React.js, I used the same logic to import it:

```
import Person from "../../util/person.class";
```

As I already expected, both deny using files that are outside their respective root folders:

[image]

[image]

I also searched in the internet about this and I found some "eject" command that, once used, there's no way back, whatever. I'd like to avoid such ways. Is there any approach where I could take in my favor?

I also want to mention that I created a tsconfig.json for backend using "tsc --init" and set the rootDir as "./src/" and outputDir as "./dist/".

Thanks.

Comment: Call it `app-lib`, and install it as a module like any other dependency, instead of importing individual files through relative paths.

Comment: You mean I should replace the "util" folder for "lib"? Do you have any source so I can read and use it as a module?

Comment: I meant that you should *make* it self-contained module, and you'd usually call that a library not a util. To install a local dependency, see e.g. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-link/ (but other package managers have similar provisions)

Comment: I liked your solution and will give it a try. Thanks Bergi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set up a third project that has the shared functionality. Then you can publish the shared package to a npm repository. And then you can install the shared package in the frontend and backend project.

Comment: No need to publish it to a repository, even.

Comment: Hello Bergi, wouldn't a local dependency be dangerous? I mean, if I accidentally delete its code, I would be lost forever, I guess. Thanks for the approach, everyone.

Comment: @RaphaelAlvarenga That's the case for *all* code you write. Nothing to do with local dependencies or otherwise. And the solution is called a backup :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to send the react from the sever then the front-end files should be under the back-end folder

```
/app root
   / back-end
      /shared-front-end-classes
      /front-end-desktop
      /front-end-mobile
```

Though this is not the best solution

The best solution is to host the front-end on a different server and make the
back-end totally functional with APIs

## For example :

I have a blog that I host the

#### Front-end:

Github pages "Support react via a small [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gh-pages)"

#### Back-end:

Hosted on Heroku

#### DB:

I am using mongoAtlas "A cloud DB"

---

**now** you have 3 separate places to hold all of your code independent of each other

Now for your other problem, you want to use the same classes over the two front-ends

For me, I usually make a small repo with all the components/ pages that I want then import this in any project for future use

I am not sure if this follows the DRY concept but you will not write your code twice

Comment: When finishing the React project, I'd build it and move it to the backend "public" folder. But the way you mentioned, the front end desktop and mobile would still complain the class is not in their respective folders, wouldn't they? The class would need to be in the backend folder, I think.

Comment: Yes, what I meant by adding them there is to add them with there classes there I will make a quick edit

Comment: I added a shared classes folder to the structure